# Why is RCov excluding views and including comments?

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rcov

I am using Rails 3, RSpec 2 and the rcov gem. 
I am running rcov on my specs with the following rake task:

```
desc "Run all specs with rcov"
 RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:rcov => spec_prereq) do |t| 
  t.rcov = true 
  t.pattern = "./spec/**/*_spec.rb" 
  t.rcov_opts = %w{--rails --include views -Ispec --exclude gems\/,spec\/,features\/,seeds\/} 
end
```

Firstly the view specs are not included in the results. How can I see code 
coverage for the views in the rcov results? 
Secondly, the code coverage for the models are quite low. 
When I look at the details it is because the comment lines are highlighted 
as not executed. 
How can I fix this? 
Lastly, it seems that most (if not all) of the method definitions are marked 
as not executed. 
Is there a way to correct this? 
Thanks, Daryn

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure rcov should work "as-is" with Rails3?

Are you doing anything to make it work - I see a couple of work-arounds on the web:

http://www.betaful.com/?p=498

https://github.com/nathanhumbert/rails_code_qa

Admittedly, I dont know RSpec and that perhaps has this covered in the way it wraps rcov...